# How to handle the onItemClick with searchbox?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onitemclick

I have a listview and some activity will open when click it. I used listview with Edittext(Search box) I used this code to open the activity. My question is how to open it in the same activity  when it gets clicked.

example this image: http://imgim.com/7091incig8869783.png

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (arg2) {
        case 0: intent = new Intent(this,abc.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
Intent intent;
switch (arg2) {
    case 0: intent = new Intent(abb.this,abc.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
 }}
```

abb is your current activity and abc is the activity you wanna navigate.

Comment: i can't gives an error (No enclosing instance of the type abc is accessible in scope)

Comment: I think you are trying to access a static variable from a non static method or vice versa sorry for the late reply